# Expected number of moves in random walk up the stairs

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, functional-equations, random-walk

A person is going along the stairs up the mountain: with probability $p$ he makes one step forward, with probability $(1-p)$ he falls, rolls down and raises only $k$ steps behind. The peak of the mountain is $n$ steps from the starting point, and there is no end of the stairs downway. What is the expected number $E_n$ of moves before achieving the peak? Both a step up and a rolling down are considered one move.

There is an obvious functional equation $E_n=1+pE_{n-1}+(1-p)E_{n+k}$, but it seems that there is not enough boundary conditions, only $E_0=0$. How can it be solved?

Comment: Hint: you can edit your question instead of deleting it.

Comment: Since one must stand on each stair between the starting point and the peak to reach the peak, $E_n=nE_1$. Another option would be to consider the asymptotics when $n\to\infty$ and to use the LLN but this simpler argument suffices to conclude that $$E_n=\frac{n}{p-k(1-p)}$$ if the denominator is positive, otherwise $E_n=+\infty$ for every $n\geqslant1$.

Comment: @Did, would you make it an answer?

Comment: @evgeny I guess user 'Did' cannot be bothered to type this up into an answer. Why don't you just type what he said and answer the question yourself? No one's gonna shame you for that, and you can get a related badge (if you haven't) as well as remove this post from clogging up the system.